# ajax - echoed images not loading on JQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

having some issues with using JQuery's .load() to load images and make a dynamic slot machine. This is the original HTML I will be loading into:

**index.php**

```
    <p id='slotContainer'>
        <?php
             echo "<img src='imgs/5.png'>";
             echo "<img src='imgs/5.png'>";
             echo "<img src='imgs/5.png'>";
         ?>
    </p>
```

This is the Javascript that is activated by a button press:

**clicked.js**

```
function clicked() {
    if (typeof processing ==='undefined' || processing===null || !processing) {
        processing= true;
        $('#playbutton').hide();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#slotContainer').load('backend.php', function() {
                processing=false;
                $('#playbutton').show();
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

And finally, this is what I'm trying to load:

**backend.php**

```
<?php
$result = array(rand(1,5),rand(1,5),rand(1,5));
echo "<img src=imgs/".$result[0].".png>";
echo "<img src=imgs/".$result[1].".png>";
echo "<img src=imgs/".$result[2].".png>";
?>
```

I have tried making the original 'slotContainer' blank and then load the images generated by 'backend.php', but for some reason this generates what I deleted out of 'slotContainer'? I have a feeling I must be overlooking something disgusting obvious. Apologies for any poor coding practices I may have displayed, I am self-taught.

EDIT: the Ajax API is linked in the  tag of 'index.php'

Comment: You may be missing the 'data' portion of the function call: .load( url, data, complete )

Comment: @Randall I tried throwing a 'dummy variable' in there, but I'm getting the same result (or lack of results, as it were)

Comment: Q: What exactly is not happening? The ajax load is erroring? Returning empty? Returning something other than you expect? Check console?

Comment: Basically, the new images are not loading. The default image is <img src='imgs/5.png'>. After the Play button is clicked, ajax should load a new set of images into 'slotContainer'. It is not doing that

Comment: This is probably a browser issue. First, adjust your `$.load();` callback so you can log the result status (and other details if necessary).  `$('...').load('backend.php',function(response,status){ console.log(status); });` then try it in a few different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I predicted, the answer was disgustingly obvious and a huge oversight on my end. I had forgotten to unlink a previous script that was stuck in a 'while' loop and was locking everything else up. Wish I had caught this before making a fool of myself.

Big thanks to all who gave me pointers. Much appreciated

Comment: Glad you figured it out. It was a head scratcher what was going bonkers for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add Ajax API
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js
before

```
<script>
function clicked() {
if (typeof processing ==='undefined' || processing===null || !processing) {
    processing= true;
    $('#playbutton').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#slotContainer').load('backend.php', function() {
            processing=false;
            $('#playbutton').show();
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry I should have said this earlier, I have it linked in 'index.php''s <head> tag. Should it be somewhere else?

Comment: you may be fix button like : `<input type="submit" id="playbutton" onclick="clicked()" value="Change" />`

Comment: That's odd. Perhaps it's my test server of choice, XAMPP Apache, that's the problem. Obviously something isn't configured properly on my end if the code is working for other folks. Thanks!